# Lag/lead groups of observation with R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this one

```
id year var
1  2000 0
1  2000 0
1  2001 1
1  2001 0
1  2001 0
1  2002 1
1  2002 0
1  2003 1
2  2004 0
2  2004 1
2  2005 0
2  2006 0
2  2006 0
2  2007 1
```

I want to group my dataframe by id and year and create a "leaded" variable by group. In other words I want to obtain this output

```
id year var leadvar
1  2000 0   1
1  2000 0   1
1  2001 1   0
1  2001 1   0
1  2001 1   0
1  2002 0   1
1  2002 0   1
1  2003 1   NA
2  2004 0   0
2  2004 0   0
2  2005 0   0
2  2006 0   1
2  2006 0   1
2  2007 1   NA
```

where leadvar is just the value taken by the variable var for the same id in the subsequent year. Can anyone help me with this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(lead_var = lead(var)) %>%
 group_by(id, year) %>%
 mutate(lead_var = last(lead_var))

      id  year   var lead_var
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>
 1     1  2000     0        1
 2     1  2000     0        1
 3     1  2001     1        0
 4     1  2001     1        0
 5     1  2001     1        0
 6     1  2002     0        1
 7     1  2002     0        1
 8     1  2003     1       NA
 9     2  2004     0        0
10     2  2004     0        0
11     2  2005     0        0
12     2  2006     0        1
13     2  2006     0        1
14     2  2007     1       NA
```